# this[string name] in Generic Collection

Tags: c#

I have a lot of collections in an application, and it occured to me that all of the objects have a similar "Name" field in my program. So I wanted to do something like this...

```
public partial class Listable<T> : List<T> where T : IListable
{
    public T this[string name]
    {
        get { // ..... ? 
        set;
    }
}
```

But I ...am a little bit stuck as to where to go from there. How do I iterate the collection I am inheriting from in the class? I mean, surely the list of items in the base class be iterated, right?

This is in .NET 3.5.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to iterate over the collection or do you want find out how to get Name value using reflection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are inheriting from List you can do this:

```
return this.Single(l => l.Name == name); // Throws exception
```

Or

```
return this.SingleOrDefault(l => l.Name == name); // Returns null
```

As LBushkin mentioned unless you really want to add more functionality you can keep using

```
List<IListable>
```

Then you can just make the call like this:

```
var item = list.Single(l => l.Name == "Jim");
```

Finally you may want to consider the Dictionary object:

```
var v = new ListableItem("Jim");
var items = new Dictionary<String, IListable>();

items.Add(v.Name, v);

IListable result;

result = items["Jim"];  // Object.ReferenceEquals(result, v) == true
result = items["Matt"];  // Throws KeyNotFoundException

if (!items.TryGetValue("Matt", out result))
{
    // Matt is not in the dictionary
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect. I think I may also explore the dictionary idea, as stated above.

Comment: Yeah, the dictionary solution will give you the best performance.

Comment: Well, the name field is part of the actual class, though. How would that work with a dictionary object?

Comment: Let me quick type up an example.

Comment: The problem with the Dictionary is that the data comes from an XML store , and is deserialized. So I never have a place in code I can type that stuff in.

Answer (score 3):

Since you seem to already have an interface each type implements, you can then avoid using a special collection, and use LINQ to perform the lookup. You may also want to consider using a Dictionary rather than a list, if your primary use case is object lookup by name. If you do choose to create a dictionary, you should ensure that the `Name` property of these objects is immutable, otherwise you may find the wrong item (or no item) when you perform the lookup.

```
public interface IListable { string Name { get; } } // assumed interface

public class SomeType : IListable { ... }

var listObjects = new List<SomeType>() { /* populate collection */ };
var foundObject = listObjects.Where( x => x.Name == "theNameToFind" )
                             .SingleOrDefault();
```

You can, of course, create your own extension method to make this a single line operation:

```
public static class ListExt
{
    public static T Find<T>( this IList<T> list, string name ) where T : IListable 
    {
        return list.Where( x => x.Name == name ).SingleOrDefault();
    }
}

// we can now do this:
var listObjects = new List<SomeType>() { /* populate collection */ };
var item = listObjects.Find( "nameToFind" );
```

Answer (score 2):

You should just be able to use `this` to refer to the list and iterate over it:

```
foreach (IListable item in this)
{
    if (item.Name == name)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```